# In smarty div position fixed is not working

Tags: smarty

In smarty div position fixed is not working. While this one is working in simple php.

Answer (score 2):

This will hardly be a Smarty problem. Just save both HTML pages and locally and compare. What's the difference? Maybe you could even use a diff tool for this. Have you tried to validate the [HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) and the [CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)? It might also give you some hints.

This is a CSS problem - not a Smarty one. You should consider adding more information to the question and tag it with HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1):

you can see what's wrong using FireBug with Firefox.